# Coluna INT aceitando somente valores positivo

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tipagem, int

Como definir tabela no MySQL para que determinada coluna `INT` aceite somente valores positivo?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

O ideal é fazer esse tipo de controle antes do banco de dados, mandar o dado errado para retornar um erro e ter que corrigir é a pior forma de utilização de exceção que já vi. Se sabe que só pode positivo valide isto antes na aplicação, simplifique-a e ganhe performance e robustez. De fato o MySQL é um banco de dados ótimo para armazenamento, mas péssimo para lidar com este tipo de coisa, por isso é melhor deixá-lo bem simples e tratar tudo na aplicação.

Se quiser pode documentar com uma restrição na coluna, mas ela não será respeitada:

```
CHECK (coluna > 0)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Other/Check.sql).

Não use `unsigned`, ele não funciona também, e não dará erro, apenas truncará o negativo, que não é o que deseja.

Comment: Senão me engano as engines do Mysql ignoram esta *constraint* `check`, talvez o AP precise de uma trigger para isso.

Comment: @gato fui ver a documentação e você tem razão. Bom eu não gosto do MySQL para banco de dados *full feature*, acho ele bom como mecanismo de armazenamento e isso ele faz bem, então vale o que eu já respondi, faz na aplicação que é melhor. *Trigger* pode até resolver, mas é gambi, e é um motivo a mais pra fazer nada. Depois eu penso em mudar a resposta pra deixar isso mais claro. E pra deixar claro, `unsigned` também não funciona.

Comment: Ele até chega a analisar, mas ignora. No caso da trigger é que o AP não contextualizou a situação e também não especificou qual linguagem esta a usar, eu deixaria na linguagem mesmo como uma regra de domínio, para mudar seria mais fácil sem tem que mexer no esquema da tabela :)

Comment: No caso de uma API, quando recebe o método post, é gravado as informações em uma tabela chamada "movimentacao", e posteriormente a trigger grava a nova quantidade do produto na tabela estoque.
O produto recém gravado na tabela movimentação, já atingiu a quantidade 0 na tabela estoque, assim é gravado quantidades negativas, naquele produto. Isso que não desejo!
Conforme vocês comentaram o ideal é fazer o tratamento desta validação via aplicação.
O ideal seria executar um método GET obtendo o valor do estoque, daquele produto verificando antes de gravar na tabela movimentações?

Comment: Aí depende da aplicação que eu não sei, mas pode ser.

Answer (score 1):

tudo bem?

Como os amigos acima já mencionaram, o MYSQL não tem como limitar o aceite de números positivos somente. Caso use o **"unsigned"**, o que ele vai fazer é "converter" seu numero negativo para positivo, e isso pode comprometer sua base de dados.

A melhor maneira de fazer essa limitação é através da linguagem que você estiver utilizando para fazer a conexão com o banco. Qual linguagem você esta utilizando, talvez consiga te ajudar.

Abraços.

Comment: Estou fazendo uma API que simula a baixa de estoque de produtos.
Atraves do metodo POST passando o Json com as informações, é gravado na tabela de movimentações, e posteiormente é baixada na tabela estoque através de um trigger no banco de dados.
O que acontece é que na tabela estoque quando um produto já atingiu a quantidade 0, ao receber o metodo POST na tabela movimentações a trigger faz novamente a baixa, ficando com o estoque negativo.
Estou utilizando a linguagem NodeJS + MySQL.

Comment: consegue este trecho do código para tentarmos compreender e passar a solução.